# script for multiple files then create a mvfile script to move files to directory think i made a mistake

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
n=$1

for ((i=1;i<=n;++i)); do    
   touch "photo$1.gif"    
   touch "photo$2.gif"    
   touch "photo$3.gif"
done
```

// this is is my create_files script where i want to make the same multiple copies i dont think 
its right

I want to move .gif files to a directory doing it by script so this is my mvfile script

```
ext=.gif    
dir=$photo // not sure to see if directory exist yet     
if [ -d "$photo"];then    
   echo "file exists"    
   if [ ! od "$photo"]; then    
      mkdir photo #// make directory in case it does not exist    
   fi

for file in "*.gif"; do    
   my $file $dir
done
```

I tried to see if it worked kept getting syntax error for this line

Comment: What is value of `$photo`?

Comment: value? i was trying to make $photo the directory i guess i messed up...

Comment: ok what do you think `dir=$photo` supposed to be doing?

Comment: to see if the directory exists?

Comment: But you're not assigning anything to `photo` variable anywhere.

Comment: @LeninSojoAzulyOro : I admire your desire to learn. Feel free to add a comment to any of your questions with `@shellter` to ask for me to look at it. I'm not always around, AND I can't help with everything but I'll try and make sure your question is going to be clear enough not to get closed or down-voted. Just remember that the best questions contain 1. small sample data, 2. the output you need given that sample data, 3. an attempt to have solved the problem, 4. current output from your program (AND exact error messages). 5. your thoughts or questions about why it's not working. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you want something like this-

`create_files` Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1

for ((i=1;i<=n;++i))
do
    touch "photo${i}.gif"
done
```

`move_files` Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls -1 | grep ".gif"`

DIR="photos"

if [ -e $DIR ]
then
    echo "$DIR exists"
else
    mkdir $DIR
    mv $FILES $DIR
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not **way** off, ust a **bit** off. What is giving you problems is you are assigning `dir=$photo` and then testing `$photo` instead of `$dir` (while the effect should be the same, since you will be using `dir` in your `mv $file $dir` command, you are better server testing `$dir`). Since you are using `mv` where the second argument is a directory, then you can move all `gif` files to a new location in a sngle command:

```
mv *.gif $dir
```

That is all you need. Now to set it up in the script:

```
dir="$photo"                     # Always quote string variables!
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then           # test if "$dir" (quoted) exists
    echo "dir: '$dir' exists"    # provide output showing success (not reqd)
    mv *.gif "$dir"              # move all .gif files in $PWD to "$dir"
else
    echo "dir: '$dir' not found" # provide feedback on failure
fi
```

Or a short version:

```
dir="$photo"; [ -d "$dir" ] && mv *.gif "$dir" || echo "dir: '$dir' not found"
```

Comment: Oh Dear, a doe, a dear, to many `dir` to keep track of. Thank You! Fixed.